# Sign in with LinkedIn PHP Code issue

Tags: javascript, php, html, web, linkedin-api

The code down below was implemented by me to retrieve specific details from LinkedIn accounts and save them to the database. Although they are retrieving correctly data is not saving to the database correctly. Not sure something wrong with my query. Please have a look at my coding and point out the issue. Any sort of help would be really appreciated.

```
    <?php

    session_start();

    $client_id = "";
    $client_secret = "";
    $redirect_uri = "http://localhost:8888/Exercise/callback.php";
    $csrf_token = random_int(1111111, 9999999);
    $scopes = "r_basicprofile%20r_emailaddress";

    function curl($url, $parameters)
    {
        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $parameters);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
        $headers = [];
        $headers[] = "Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded";
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $headers);
        $result = curl_exec($ch);
        return $result;
    }

    function getCallback()
    {
      $client_id = "";
      $client_secret = "";
      $redirect_uri = "http://localhost:8888/Exercise/callback.php";
      $csrf_token = random_int(1111111, 9999999);
      $scopes = "r_basicprofile%20r_emailaddress";

        if (isset($_REQUEST['code'])) {
            $code = $_REQUEST['code'];
            $url = "https://www.linkedin.com/oauth/v2/accessToken";
            $params = [
                'client_id' => $client_id,
                'client_secret' => $client_secret,
                'redirect_uri' => $redirect_uri,
                'code' => $code,
                'grant_type' => 'authorization_code',
            ];
            $accessToken = curl($url,http_build_query($params));
            $accessToken = json_decode($accessToken)->access_token;

            $url = "https://api.linkedin.com/v1/people/~:(id,firstName,lastName,pictureUrls::(original),headline,publicProfileUrl,location,industry,positions,email-address )?format=json&oauth2_access_token=" . $accessToken;
            $user = file_get_contents($url, false);

     $User = json_decode(post_curl($url)); // Request user information on received token

$query = "INSERT INTO `linkedti_scheduler`.`users`
                   (`userid`,
                   `firstName`,
                   `lastName`,
                   `emailAddress`,
                   `position`,
                   `location`,
                   `profileURL`,
                   `headline`)

                   VALUES

                   ('$id',
           '$firstName',
           '$lastName',
           '$emailAddress',
           '$position',
           '$location',
           '$profileURL',
           '$headline')";
           mysqli_query($connection,$query);


            return (json_decode($user));



        }
    }
     ?>
```

Comment: You did not assign any values to your query variables which is $id,$firstname etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to reference the fields using the `$User` object like this:

```
 $User = json_decode(post_curl($url)); // Request user information on received token

$query = "INSERT INTO `linkedti_scheduler`.`users`
               (`userid`,
               `firstName`,
               `lastName`,
               `emailAddress`,
               `position`,
               `location`,
               `profileURL`,
               `headline`)

               VALUES

               ('$id',
       '$User->firstName',
       '$User->lastName',
       '$User->emailAddress',
       '$User->position',
       '$User->location',
       '$User->profileURL',
       '$User->headline')";
```

Also, be warned that you are not using an MySQL escaping here -- I suggest using a prepared query to prevent any issues with single quotes:

https://secure.php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php